# Remove roles of a user with discord.py without commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to remove a role(s) of my discord-server users without the need of using a command, only calling a python function and when calling it, it will remove the roles automatically, is that possible, if so, how can I do it?

```
async def removeRoles(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild, name='Miembro')
    await user.remove_roles(role)
```

The above code is an example of removing roles **WITH** help of a command, I want without it, and using it like something as this:

```
// calling this function somewhere in other module.py
removeRoles("user_discord_id", "role_to_remove") // removes the role given to the specified user
```

How can i do it with discord.py? thanks!

Comment: You know how to remove a role, so is your question how to get a user object from an id?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs no, getting a user object from an id as what I know does not get the user for the current server, thats first, and second, i need a function that is called within another py module that simply removes a specified role from a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get the guild, then its member, and remove roles that way. But you need to explain if you want to do so in a synchronous or asynchronous function. If you want to do it an async function, then it's as simple as this:

```py
# I'm guessing you have a discord.ext.commands.Bot variable called bot

guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name="GuildName") 
# Using the guild's ID to get it would be better
# But since you've used name in your example, I'm going to as well

member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, name="MemberName")

role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="RoleName")

await member.remove_roles(role)
```

However, if you want to remove the member's roles in a synchronous function, be prepared to use the Discord API and the `requests` library. This page in the Discord API should be helpful: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#remove-guild-member-role.

Something like this should do the trick:

```py
#  I'm guessing you have a discord.ext.commands.Bot variable called bot

guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name="GuildName")
# Using the guild's ID to get it would be better
# But since you've used name in your example, I'm going to as well

member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, name="MemberName")

role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="RoleName")

headers = {"authorization": "Bot " + "your_token_goes_here"}

requests.delete(f"https://discord.com/api/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{member.id}/roles/{role.id}", headers=headers)
```